# Aptana issues with HTML and PHP code

Tags: php, html, tags

I use Aptana Studio 3 and I have two questions:

1. The index file of my website is a PHP file and in this file I use HTML code and some php scripts. Aptana recognizes the PHP code and allow me to close/open pieces of code with the [-] and [+] on the left vertical bar. While this doesn't happen for the HTML tags. How can I have this feature for both PHP and HTML codes in a single PHP file?
2. Is there a way to select a text and apply an HTML tag by clicking a button or by a shortcut? Example: I select a word and I apply the tag `<b>...</b>` by clicking button/shortcut.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843072/aptana-code-folding?

Comment: did you ever come up with a solution to your problems?  if you have please share them as a Self Answer so that if someone else has an issue like this they will have a good spot to start their search from. (*and earn yourself some Rep*)